# range() & xrange() in Python 3

Tags: python

Let's suppose we want to create a loop function with billion iterations.

if we use `for i in range(0, 1000000000)` in Python 2 it would create a **LIST** with billion data members, which takes a lot of space.

By using `for i in xrange(0, 1000000000)`, in Python 2 it doesn't ***create*** a list, but selects one index at a time.

in PYTHON 3, there is no `xrange()`, and `range()` works in either case.

How can we save space in Python 3 in this case?

Comment: Python 3's `range` is equivalent to python 2's `xrange`. I don't think you need to save any more space.

Comment: `range()` in Python 3 works much like `xrange()` in Python 2--almost no memory is used, and each value is calculated and given when needed. There is no function like this in Python 3 that makes a list--to do that you use `list(range(...))`.